# Adding property in nested for-loop causes same values for each parent for-loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

I have an array containing information on playing cards (cardInfo). A sample of the array is added in the code below. Since each card may have duplicates, I want to use this information to create a deck by pushing its information to a new array (drawPile) for each card of that type (the property 'frequency1').

```
var common = 4;
var uncommon = 3;
var rare = 2;
var cardInfo = [
    {name:'Card A',frequency1:common,frequency2:rare,frequency3:0}, 
    {name:'Card B',frequency1:common,frequency2:uncommon,frequency3:0},
    {name:'Card C',frequency1:uncommon,frequency2:uncommon,frequency3:0}
];

var drawPile = [];
for (var cType = 0; cType < cardInfo.length; cType++) {
    for (var freq = 0; freq < cardInfo[cType].frequency1; freq++) {
        drawPile.push(cardInfo[cType]);
        console.log(drawPile.length - 1);
        drawPile[(drawPile.length - 1)].id = (drawPile.length - 1);
        console.log(drawPile[(drawPile.length - 1)]);
    }
}
```

The resulting console log, however, shows that all 4 "Card A" cards have the id property 3, all 4 "Card B" cards have the id property 7, and all 3 "Card C" cards have the id property 10. It is as if the nested (freq) loop only runs for all .push() commands before it adds the id property.

More strangeness: when I run this code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uajvpwvg/), I can replicate these results if I first run it and then open the console log, but when I run it after the console lof is already open, it works as intended.

How do I ensure each card gets a unique identifier?

EDIT: It gets even stranger when I get the exact same results if I create a completely new for loop specifically for adding the id property as seen in [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/uajvpwvg/1/).

Comment: @Gavin, that's strange. This is the result I have when I run first, open console later: http://oi67.tinypic.com/2r2ureb.jpg

Comment: "*all 4 "Card A" cards have the id property 3*" - of course they do. They are all the same object.  You'll need to create new objects in the loop to give them different property values. An assignment does not copy an object.

Comment: @Bergi Am I not creating a new object (although with the same properties and values) every time I'm pushing it to the drawPile array?

Comment: No, you're pushing a new reference to the same object, over and over.

Comment: So what can I do to end up with a drawPIle array where every index contains an object with a unique id property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you loop around the `cardInfo` collection, for each `cardInfo` instance, you loop around the frequencies. Technically for each frequency you are pulling in the same instance of the `cardInfo`, so technically you are updating the same `cardInfo` instance for each frequency iteration. Now your next statement will be but I write `console.log` for each iteration. But when you debug the code, `console.log` outputs correctly, however I'm not sure whether this is the case when it is run through without a debug. So how can you resolve this?

After determining that it was modifying the same instance for each iteration of the related frequency, I decided to clone the card (I'm not saying this is a great idea, but it proves the concept). I achieved this by using:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cardInfo[cType]));
```

Again this is not the most performant way of achieving this, but highlights where I believe the issue lies.

I have applied this change to a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3o25q314/) (I've also simplified the code a little) and if you remove the cloning it operates as you currently see it, but with the cloning it works as you would expect it.

I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing object reference to the drawPile array in the loop. That's why all "Card A" cards have the same ID as array contains same reference. you have to clone the object before pushing into the loop. You can make the below change to your code.

```
  for (var freq = 0; freq < cardInfo[cType].frequency1; freq++) {
            drawPile.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cardInfo[cType])));
            console.log(drawPile.length - 1);
            drawPile[(drawPile.length - 1)].id = (drawPile.length - 1);
            console.log(drawPile[(drawPile.length - 1)]);
        }
```